# import an existing SSM Parameter and add as an Task Image environment variable in ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-ssm

I have parameters in SSM that is saved looking something like `/dbUrl/prod` , `/dbUrl/dev` and so on where it is in the format `/dbUrl/${stage}`.

I want to get this parameter and set as an environment variable for the task definition so I have a different value for the variable based on different environment. Right now stuck on how to import an existing parameter

Also is it possible to access the `DB_URL` value as `process.env.DB_URL` inside my node.js code after I manage to set the environment variable here

Docs I was following
[ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html)
[ApplicationLoadBalancedTaskImageOptions#secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedTaskImageOptions.html#secrets)

```js
      const socketService = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, `socketService${props.stage}`, {
        cluster: cluster,
        loadBalancer: loadBalancer ,
        memoryLimitMiB: 2048,
        cpu: 1024,
        desiredCount: 2,
        listenerPort: 1111,
        taskImageOptions: {
          image: ContainerImage.fromAsset("../socket"),
          environment: {
          },
          secrets: {
            DB_URL: //how to import existing /dbUrl/${props.stage} from SSM
          }
        },
        
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You linked to documentation on the `secrets` prop of the `ApplicationLoadBalancedTaskImageOptions`. The docs specify that the type of the `secrets` prop is `{ [string]: Secret }`.

You can follow the link to the documentation of [Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Secret.html#static-fromwbrssmwbrparameterparameter) to see how it can be obtained. You will see that it has a `fromSsmParameter` method, which is what you need. That method takes in an `IParameter`.

To import an existing String Parameter, you can use one of the `from*` methods defined in the `StringParameter` class. For example, you can use [`fromSecureStringParameterAttributes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html#static-fromwbrsecurewbrstringwbrparameterwbrattributesscope-id-attrs)

Comment: i did `DB_URL: Secret.fromSsmParameter(StringParameter.fromStringParameterName(this, 'db', `/dbUrl/${props.stage}`))`  and it seems to work. I was also able to access this value as `process.env.DB_URL` in my node.js code